# Error Load Failed with Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 On Playing Video in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, video-player

I am using

- Xamarin.forms to create an IPTV app
- Xamarin.ios updated to the latest version 12.8.0.2
- VS2019

When I play a video in iOS with http URL I get this error

> 2019-05-03 20:53:18.527273+0500 GemsIPTV.Forms.iOS[7707:141362] Task .<1> **load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"** UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.MockWebsite.com/123.mkv, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.MockWebsite.com/123.mkv, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask .<1>"
>   ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]

I am using custom renderers for videoplayer given in Xamarin.Forms [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/web-videos)

- I can play videos in android from http and https URLs
- I added NSAllowsArbitraryLoads for the ATS in iOS (for http URLs)

This is the VideoPlayer [Demo/Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/VideoPlayerDemos/) I followed in addition to the Documentation Linked Above.

I tried to use the Xamarin.MediaManager Plugin as well but the same error occurs while trying to play the video

The Code below is for the VideoPlayerPage

```
public partial class VideoPlayerPage : ContentPage
{
    public VideoPlayerPage(string URL)
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            VideoPlayer videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
                Source = new UriVideoSource
                {
                    Uri = URL
                },
                AutoPlay = true,
                AreTransportControlsEnabled = true
            };

            Content = videoPlayer;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

When I play the video file in iOS with http URL the Play button has a Slash (Line) through it and the video keeps loading and eventually stops loading but doesn't play, I want it to play like the https url play the video after loading.

Comment: Hi, does this is the played url (http://www.MockWebsite.com/123.mkv) ?I found this can url can not be opened.Maybe url source should be checked first.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I replaced the URL while posting here(The URL I am using is generated using tokens and expires after a while), Although I tried several different URLs which were working on my Computer and the Android App created using same code in Xamarin.forms but not on iOS e.g (linkOne:(http://184.72.239.149/vod/smil:BigBuckBunny.smil/playlist.m3u8
)  linkTwo:(https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8
)  LinkThree:(https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4))

So I believe URL is not the problem

Comment: Okey, I have runned the shared sample , it occurs the same in IOS.I will chek it which problem is.

Comment: It was working before the Xamarin.IOS update but no URL is working on iOS after the update

Comment: Hi, I Have solved my problem. Hope this is helpful for you. I found this to be related to the speed of the network. When the network speed is good, the video can be loaded on the iOS device, but it still takes a little waiting time. It seems that the web uploading web video on iOS is not as sensitive as Android. So I suggest you try to use the small video of the local network to do a test to see if you can load the video. The MKV format video is not recommended, and the MP4 video can be tested.